# knockout.js and bootstrap modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, custom-binding

I'm using some code I've found on SO (the second answer here: [knockout.js - deferred databinding for modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626780/knockout-js-deferred-databinding-for-modal)).

The details aren't displaying in the form though.

```
  rowClick: function(data){
    console.log("in row click");
    console.log(data); // produces data as per debug below
    // load the transaction when a row is clicked
    self.EditingTransaction(data);
    console.log(self.EditingTransaction()); // produces data as per debug below (not as a observable though)
  },
```

here is the view code:

```
<div data-bind="modal: EditingTransaction" class="fade">
    <form data-bind="submit: $root.SaveTransaction">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
        <h3>
            Editing transaction</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label>Date</label> <input type="text" data-bind="text: Date"/></br>
        <label>Category</label> <input type="text" data-bind="text: Category"/></br>
        <label>Subcategory</label> <input type="text" data-bind="text: Subcategory"/></br>
        <label>Amount</label> <input type="text" data-bind="text: Amount"/></br>
        <label>Notes</label> <input type="text" data-bind="text: Notes"/></br>
        <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.EditingTransaction, null, 2)"></pre>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
         <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: $root.SaveTransaction">Save changes</a>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The dialog is displaying when data is assigned to editTransaction - the pre ko.toJSON debug HTML displays this:

```
{
  "ID": "1231",
  "TransactionType": "Withdrawal",
  "Date": "2012-11-07",
  "Category": "cat",
  "Subcategory": "sub cat",
  "Amount": "-50.00",
  "currency": "GBP",
  "Notes": "",
  "AccountName": "Account 2",
  "Payee": "Cheque"
}
```

I have had a search about and seen comments about the data not being available when the modal is initialised (when page loads) but I that doesn't make sense to me (I believe the point bindings is that they update when the view when data changes and also the debug statement is working ok). I have tried without the with in the binding code and also with a reference to $root in the data-bind text.

So, any ideas why it isn't working would be great.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific what's not working for you? Is it the rowClick function that is not working as intended?

Comment: yes missed that - the values weren't displaying the form. Answer below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PICNIC :-)

The bindings on the input tag should have been value not text... I've been looking at that on and off for a day - within 10 mins of posting the answer hits me!